# Submit list data in ajax does not work with List<data> in Controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, submit

Anyone can help me explain this fact, it is about the way MVC deserialise submitted data.

**Assume that we have a JSON object like below:**

```
var submitedData = {
  name = "Gary",
  jobs = [{id:1, jobName:'IT'}, {id:2, jobName:'Teacher'}]
}
```

**We do an ajax request to server:**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '@Url.Action("ActionName")',
contentType:'application/json',
traditional: true,
JSON.stringify(submitedData),
success: function(){}
});
```

Of course, our view model has to contain exactly what the JSON data is, maybe like below

```
public class ViewModel{
public string name {get;set;}
public List<Job> jobs {get;set;}
}
public class Job{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string JobName {get;set;}
}
```

My question is: When we call ajax request like above, the job list can not be bound to view model in the controller.
The root reason is that we defined jobs in ViewModel is a List<>. If we change to `IEnumerable<>`, controller will be able to bind the jobs:

```
public class ViewModel{
public string name {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<Job> jobs {get;set;}
}
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks for all ideas from you!
p/s: 'Cause this sample code is manually written by my own then it maybe still has several other problems.

Please ignore, just focus on my question :P.

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is incorrect. It should be

```
var submitedData = {
  name : "Gary",
  jobs : [{id:1, jobName:'IT'}, {id:2, jobName:'Teacher'}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Bhuban Shrestha, even if i correct it, the job list is still not bound to the MVC model. I am working on a commercial project then i could not show you the source code exactly. So I manually wrote a sample here for describing my question.